# How to get [a b] as my output when I pass a,b using values(a,b) in the same order?

Tags: node.js, gremlin, janusgraph

I am using gremlin console to check my query working or not. I am able to get the required data but in the reverse order.
In the end of my query, I am using

```
    values.('id','name').fold()
```

But the output I am getting is [name id].
How to get the output as [id name]?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Gremlin typically doesn't do anything to preserve order and relies on the order provided by the underlying graph database. If you need order then you need to specify the order in some way. I think that you could use `union()` for that:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V(1).union(values('name'),values('age')).fold()
==>[marko,29]
gremlin> g.V(1).union(values('age'),values('name')).fold()
==>[29,marko]
```

I'm not sure if it's a great idea to rely on `union()` though. Like TinkerGraph should respect the order specified there, but I'm not sure if other graphs will. Perhaps a better solution would be to explicit with `order()`:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).properties('name','age').order().by(key).value()
==>29
==>marko
```

That's alphabetical sort by key though and not the order you typed them. Ultimately though if you're just validating results it would probably be better to just return a `Map` with `project()`

```
gremlin> g.V(1).project('name','age').by('name').by('age')
==>[name:marko,age:29]
gremlin> g.V(1).project('age','name').by('age').by('name')
==>[age:29,name:marko]
gremlin> g.V(1).project('age','name').by('age').by('name').next().getClass()
==>class java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

As you can see `project()` preserves `order()` as it uses a `LinkedHashMap` and executes the `by()` modulators in the order they are defined. What's neat about that is that you really wanted that `List` form you were asking about in your initial question you could then just grab the values from the `Map`:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).project('name','age').by('name').by('age').select(values)
==>[marko,29]
gremlin> g.V(1).project('age','name').by('age').by('name').select(values)
==>[29,marko]
```

Hopefully one of these approaches works for your situation.

Comment: I have used valueMap() in such a way that the output is in the form of array of objects. Then it is easy for me to access. I have thought that if the output is in the same order as of my parameters,then there is an ease of access(because of fold() which gives an array).Thank you,i will try the above approaches as well.